# CSS shapes - Triangle design

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Can we create the following image using CSS only?
[image]

I am able to create a right angled triangle. But I am unable to create this specific shaped triangle. ANy help will be greatly appreciated.

Code for right angled triangles design :

```css
#triangle,
#triangle3 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 100px 0 0 100px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #ff0033;
  float: left;
}
#triangle2,
#triangle4 {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 0 100px 100px 0;
  border-color: transparent #294fa3 transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  left: -100px;
}
#triangle3 {
  position: relative;
  left: -100px;
}
#triangle4 {
  position: relative;
  left: -200px;
  /*specifically for 4*/
}
```

```html
<div id="triangle"></div>
<div id="triangle2"></div>
<div id="triangle3"></div>
<div id="triangle4"></div>
```

Comment: Use `transform: skewx();`

Comment: I have tried skewx, it only complicates the positioning of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoting The Pragmatic:
" transforms are less supported "

So I found a way out without it:
HTML:

```
<div id="triangle1"></div>
<div id="triangle2">
<div id="triangle3"></div>
<div id="triangle4"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#triangle1 {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
#triangle2

{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid blue;
    position:relative;
    margin-left:50px;
}
#triangle3
{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 100px solid red;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-100px;

}
#triangle4
{
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 50px solid transparent;
    border-right: 50px solid transparent;
    border-top: 100px solid blue;
    position:relative;
    margin-top:-100px;
    margin-left:50px;

}
```

Here is the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/9rgc728w/

*I do agree my answer is **long***

Comment: Nice! I've also edited my answer, ad added a transform-less sol. Please see.

Comment: @ThePragmatick +1 as your is a way shorter method :)

Comment: I've just grouped up the selectors. If you'll do the same, your snippet will be smaller than mine :)

Comment: @ThePragmatick do u notice the triangle 2 div is not closed.When i close the tag , the pattern gets messy. So do u know  y it  happens? or should i post it as another question :)

Comment: Yes. Its happening because if you don't close a tag, it closes in the end. So, the style you applied to div 2 is now applied to div 2,3, and 4 too!

Comment: @JakeMikail No probs:)

Answer (score 3):

This is possible using a single `div` element with a :pseudo-element and `transform: skew()`.

```css
div, div:after {
  position: relative;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-right: 200px solid #2B3FA5;
  border-bottom: 75px solid #FF0000;
  transform: skew(-35deg);
  margin-left: 30px;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left: 200px;
  transform: skew(0deg);
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Actually, these triangles are separate li's of a list (with icons). So I wanted a separated solution.

Comment: @JakeMikail: One question because you have indicated that it is a list. Do you want content inside the triangles? If yes, then getting the triangle done with the border hack may not be the best option.

Comment: @JakeMikail - Why? What do you see?

Comment: Nothing. There's a navbar on top. And the body is completely blank. Please post on Fiddle! Thank you.

Comment: @JakeMikail - http://jsfiddle.net/s1ww6ozf/. Btw, [this is what I see on Firefox and Chrome](http://s25.postimg.org/vqdavazdb/fire.png). I've put those triangles in four different `li`s.

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) can draw this background:

**HTML:**

```
<div></div>
```

**Necessary CSS:**

```
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, red 50%, blue 50%);
  background-size: 50% 100%;

  transform: skewX(-35deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
}
```

**Output Image:**

[image: Output Image]

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(lightgreen, green);
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, red 50%, blue 50%);
  background-size: 50% 100%;

  transform: skewX(-35deg);
  transform-origin: 0 100%;
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>

</div>
```